# Listar todos os meses em um intevalo, ou na query ou na programação?

Tags: php, sql

Estou fazendo um gráfico que lista uma certa quantidade por mês, mas pode ter mès que não tem nada, com isso não me retorna nenhum valor e não lista no gráfico.

Não sei se devo fazer a alteração na query ou na programação, será que alguém consegue me ajudar?

A minha query esta assim:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt_validade, '%y-%m') as anoMes, count(*) as qtde
FROM tabela
WHERE dt_validade > '{$today}'
GROUP BY anoMes
ORDER BY anoMes
```

o retorno dela é mais ou menos isso

> ```
> anoMes  | qtde
> 14-08   | 2
> 14-09   | 5
> 14-12   | 10
> 14-12   | 10
> 14-12   | 10
> 15-01   | 1
> 15-03   | 1
> ```

e com isso, no php eu rodo um loop no resultado, jogo os dados para um array que mando um json_encode para os dados para o gráfico, mas com isso só irá me mostrar no gráfico dados dos meses 08, 09 e 12, mas preciso que mostre também dos meses 10 e 11 com valores zerados.

E resumindo, o que fiz na programação foi isso:

```
$cols = array(
    array(
        'Período', 
        'Quantidade'
    )
);
$rows = array();

$query = "A query passada";    
$result = $query->result();
foreach ($result as $r) {
    array_push($rows, array(
        $r->mesAno, 
        (int) $r->qtde
    ));
}    

$dados = array_merge($cols, $rows);     

return json_encode($dados);
```

E como sugestão que me foi dada, o resultado esperado é esse:

```
anoMes  | qtde
14-08   | 2
14-09   | 5
14-10   | 0
14-11   | 0
14-12   | 10
15-01   | 1
15-03   | 1
```

Segue link com o build no [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c566/3), assim imagino que posso ficar um pouco mais claro

Comment: Eu realmente não posso entender sua questão. De que outra forma você poderia enviar uma consulta ao BD senão através de SQL? Se a pergunta for algo como CURRENT_DATE vs date("2014-01-01"), isso pouco importa! Sua consulta será enviada apenas uma vez.

Comment: Eu também não vejo outra forma de enviar minha consulta ao BD se não com sql, tanto que é assim que estou fazendo e pretendo fazer. Mas a questão é que eu preciso do resultado com todos os meses mesmo que com a quantidade zerada e não sei como faço e nem sei se faço na minha query ou na programação.

Comment: Nesse caso, especificamente, não importa o método. Opte pelo mais prático.

Comment: E vc consegue me ajudar no que é o mais prático, e como fazer, sendo que estou pensando e tentando e não conseguindo uma solução!? Obrigado

Comment: @MarceloDiniz - Já que nossos colegas tiveram algumas dúvidas em entender seu problema, minha sugestão é que vc edite o posto e add um 'resultado esperado'.. exemplo: 08-14 |2 ... 09-14 | 5 ... 10-14 | 0 ... 11-14| 0.. 12-14   | 10 acho que ficaria mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

Não ficou a coisa mais linda do mundo, mas funcionou:

```
$rows = array();

$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt_validade, '%m-%y') as anoMes, count(*) as qtde
          FROM tabela
          WHERE dt_validade > now()
          GROUP BY anoMes
          ORDER BY dt_validade";    

$result = $query->result();
foreach ($result as $r) {
    $rows[$r->mesAno] = (int) $r->qtde;
}    

reset($rows);
list($mes, $ano) = explode('-', key($rows));
$current = strtotime(($ano+2000).'-'.$mes.'-01');

end($rows);
list($mes, $ano) = explode('-', key($rows));
$last = strtotime(($ano+2000).'-'.$mes.'-01');

$dates = array();
while( $current <= $last ) { 
    $dates[date('m-y', $current)] = 0;
    $current = strtotime('+1 month', $current);
}

$rows = array_merge($dates, $rows);
$dados = array( array('Período', 'Quantidade'));
foreach($rows as $key => $value) $dados[] = array($key, $value);

return json_encode($dados);
```

Comment: Olha só, realmente, como vc disse, funcionou mesmo, não é a coisa mais linda, mas nem sempre é, e até por ainda não vou marcar como resposta aceita, mas já como útil ;) .. Agradeço mesmo, agora vou ver melhor o que fazer aqui com essa parte, mas com certeza já me deu uma luz. Valew

Comment: Então @Jader como eu disse, a solução que vc passou funcionou, mas dai fui fazer um teste colocando dados para janeiro e março de 2015 dai já me quebrou todo. Dai uma das coisas que já vi que teria que alterar era na query, algo que já fiz, agora estou vendo de alterar na programação também, caso saiba de algo agradeço.

Comment: Testei com intervalos de 12-14 a 05-15 e funcionou direitinho, note que mudei a forma como a variável $rows é populada, o mesAno entra como key, pegue todo o meu código e coloque apenas a query.

Comment: Sim, eu notei isso que vc disse e ainda assim não funcionou, dai alterei a query como pode ser vista (até no sqlfiddle) e tbm fiz uma pequena alteração no código que você postou que ajudou muito mesmo. As alterações que fiz foi trocar mes por ano que com isso ele retorna as sequencia correta.

Comment: Realmente a ordem correta é fundamental, e só com o ano na frente o MySQL vai ordenar corretamente, nos meus testes populei o array manualmente na ordem correta...

Comment: @MarceloDiniz acabo de perceber que não precisava mudar o formato da data, bastava mudar o order by para: `ORDER BY dt_validade` testei no sqlfiddle e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Nossa, que cabeção que eu fui, eu também nem tinha percebido isso e tive um pequeno trabalho aqui a mais. Valew e isso é que sirva de lição para não esquecer desses pequenos detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Meus conhecimentos em PHP são muito limitados, mas eu posso tentar ajudar com uma solução do lado do banco.

**Estabeleça o período**

```
SELECT @mindate = MIN(dt_validade), @maxdate = MAX(dt_validade) FROM tabela
```

Resultado parcial:

```
|                    @mindate |                     @maxdate |
|-----------------------------|------------------------------|
| July, 30 2014 00:00:00+0000 | March, 15 2015 00:00:00+0000 |
```

**Obtenha a lista de meses entre os dois períodos: Armazene em tabela temporária**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS 
ListaAnoMes AS
SELECT Date_format(m1, '%y-%m') AS anoMes 
FROM   (SELECT ( @mindate - INTERVAL Dayofmonth(@mindate)-1 day ) + 
               INTERVAL m month AS 
                      m1 
        FROM   (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS m 
                FROM   (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t1, 
                       (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t2, 
                       (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t3, 
                       (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t4, 
                       (SELECT @rownum :=- 1) t0) d1) d2 
WHERE  m1 <= @maxdate 
ORDER  BY m1;
```

Resultado parcial:

```
SELECT * FROM LISTAANOMES

| ANOMES |
|--------|
|  07-14 |
|  08-14 |
|  09-14 |
|  10-14 |
|  11-14 |
|  12-14 |
|  01-15 |
|  02-15 |
|  03-15 |
```

**Cruze as duas tabelas**

```
SELECT         B.AnoMes,
               Count(a.id) as qtde
FROM           ListaAnoMes as B
LEFT JOIN      tabela as A 
           ON  DATE_FORMAT(A.dt_validade, '%m-%y') = B.anoMes
GROUP BY       B.AnoMes
```

Resultado:

```
| ANOMES | QTDE |
|--------|------|
|  01-15 |    1 |
|  02-15 |    0 |
|  03-15 |    1 |
|  07-14 |    1 |
|  08-14 |    2 |
|  09-14 |    5 |
|  10-14 |    0 |
|  11-14 |    0 |
|  12-14 |   10 |
```

Comment: Ainda não cheguei a testar também a sua solução para o meu problema, mas irei fazer o teste. Mas assim, pelo que vi, eu que entendo mais de programação do que da parte de banco ficou mais fácil resolver com a solução que o @Jader passou por questão de manutenção futura, mas entendi o que passou e achei interessante também.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer um intervalo de data ?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt_validade, '%m-%y') as mesAno, count(*) as qtde
FROM tabela
WHERE dt_validade > '{$today}' OR dt_validade = NULL OR dt_validade = ''
GROUP BY mesAno
```

Não sei se está o default do campo null ou string vazia, dependendo não precisa dos 2 or, sṍ um

Comment: Eu realmente não tenho uma data final exata. O que quero é que me liste todos os meses desde o primeiro até o ultimo encontrado a partir da data de hoje.

Comment: Agora entendi o que você quer. vou editar

Comment: Sinceramente, não sei se entendeu, pois pelo que vi da sua alteração o que mudou foi no WHERE que agora não esta mais buscando em um intervalo (between) e sim buscando data a partir de hoje e data nula ou em branco. Mas isso não resolve o problema que tenho que é listar os meses no intervalo que a consulta me traz. A consulta me retorna os meses 8, 9 e 12 que são os meses que tem registro, mas preciso que me retorne os meses 8, 9, 10, 11 e 12, sendo que os meses 10 e 11 irão retornar com a quantidade igual a zero.